# $X \sim P(\lambda) \implies E(X(X-1) \ldots(X-n+1))=\lambda^{n}$

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Suppose that $X$ is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$, that is,
$$
P(X = k) = \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}, \quad \quad k \in \mathbb{N} 
$$
For $n \geq 2$, I want to prove that
$$ 
E(X(X-1) \ldots(X-n+1))=\lambda^{n}.
$$

I've tried to show by using an induction on $n$.

Let $n=2$. Using the fact that both the expectation $E(X) $ and variance $\sigma_X^2$ are equal to $\lambda$ and
$$
\sigma_X^2 = E(X^2) - E(X)^2,
$$
I obtained that $E(X^2) = \lambda + \lambda^2$. This gave me that
$$
E(X(X-1)) = E(X^2 - X) = \lambda + \lambda^2 - \lambda = \lambda^2.
$$
Hence, this made me think that induction might be a good idea to prove. But, I can't complete the induction. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Hint: write down the required expectation as a sum, factor $\lambda^r$ for a suitable $r$ and then compare the sum with the sum expansion for $e^\lambda$.

Comment: What you are after is called a **factorial moment**. You can use the generating function approach explained here for [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_moment_generating_function)

Comment: Do you know the moments of Poisson as Touchard polynomials? If so, use the orthogonality of Stirling numbers.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/268351/119261